# lightning:accordion open all sections on init

Tags: lightning-aura-components, accordion

Does anyone have an idea if it's possible to open all sections in lightning:accordion on load? Do mind that all of those sections are dynamically generated so i'm not able to reference them one by one using aura:id.

Answer (score 3):

1. You need to use `allowMultipleSectionsOpen` on accordian and set it to `true`.
2. Define `activeSectionName` on accordian and give `array` of all the sections (by `name`) to be opened by default.

Pls check below dynamic accordians with default open sections:

```
<aura:component implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId,force:lightningQuickAction,lightning:isUrlAddressable" access="GLOBAL">

    <aura:attribute name="activeSections" type="List" default="['A','B','C']" />
    <aura:attribute name="sections" type="List" default="[
                                                         {'name':'A','body':'A-body'},
                                                         {'name':'B','body':'B-body'},
                                                         {'name':'C','body':'C-body'},]" />


    <lightning:accordion
                         allowMultipleSectionsOpen="true"
                         onsectiontoggle="{! c.handleSectionToggle }"
                         activeSectionName="{! v.activeSections }" >

        <aura:iteration items="{!v.sections}" var="sec">
            <lightning:accordionSection name="{!sec.name}" label="{!'Accordion Title '+sec.name}">
                {!sec.body}
            </lightning:accordionSection>
        </aura:iteration>
    </lightning:accordion>

</aura:component>
```

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar issue and this is what I ended up doing: 
I had my list of iterated items and my list of 'activeSections' (both attributes). But I wasn't able to set the activeSections first before the page was rendered. So I added an additional method to be completed after rendering of the page to set the 'activeSections'. Hopefully this helps!

```
    //attributes    
    <aura:handler event="aura:doneRendering" action="{!c.doneRendering}"/>
    <aura:attribute name="activeSections" type="List[]" />
    <aura:attribute name="Categories" type="List[]"/>

    //example of first part of iteration/section
    <lightning:accordion 
                         allowMultipleSectionsOpen="true"
                         activeSectionName="{! v.activeSections }"
                         >

            <aura:iteration items="{!v.Categories}" var="cat">
                <lightning:accordionSection name="{!cat}" label="{!cat}">

    //doneRendering javascript method
    doneRendering: function(cmp, event, helper) {
        let cats = cmp.get("v.Categories");
        cmp.set('v.activeSections', cats);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, with attribute "activeSectionName"

```
<aura:attribute name="activeSections" type="List" default="['A','B']" />

<lightning:accordion allowMultipleSectionsOpen="true" activeSectionName="{! v.activeSections }">    
     <lightning:accordionSection name="A" label="Section1" >
          //CODE
     </lightning:accordionSection>
     <lightning:accordionSection name="B" label="Section2">
         //CODE
     </lightning:accordionSection>
</lightning:accordion>
```

Sections A (Section1) and B (Section2) are open in the load